# Is there a more efficient way to split a string into an array of integers?

Tags: python-3.x

I currently am using the following code to read in a string of integers separated by spaces as integers:

```
temp = input().split()
array =[]
for i in range(len(temp)):
    array.append(int(temp[i]))
```

it seems like there should be a more efficient way to do it. Is there? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array = list(map(int, input().split()))
```